# Linq query to return results when an ICollection is empty.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to return results from a linq query if user has a jobs positions or if the job doesn't have any positions.  I can't work out why it's not returning the results if the job doesn't have any positions specified.

Query is as follows.

```
var feedQuery = from o in _context.Jobs
                from pos in o.Positions
                where
                positions.Contains(pos.Id) || !o.Positions.Any()
                select o;
```

It works fine when the job has positions but not when the job.Positions Icollection is empty.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The line

```
from pos in o.Positions
```

creates an **inner join** between job (one) and job positions (zero or many). The effect is that it will multiply the job records when there are many positions and will filter jobs w/o related positions  (regardless of your `where` clause).

To make it work, you need to remove that statement and use `Any` based `Where` criteria on the many side (the equivalent of the SQL `EXISTS (subquery)` clause):

```
var feedQuery = 
    from o in _context.Jobs
    where !o.Positions.Any() || o.Positions.Any(pos => positions.Contains(pos.Id))
    select o;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I very much appreciate the explanation of why it wasn't working.  Teaching myself to code, so that input if very useful.  I think you might have answered a couple of my questions now.  It's great that people like you seem to be so happy to offer your expertise.